# Count and generate the legal initial states of ball sort puzzle

Tags: combinatorics

The initial state of this ball sort has $C$ colors and $C$ tubes, (and there are another $E$ empty tubes, but don't think about this).

Each color has $L$ balls, and the length of each tube is also$L$.

The initial state is a permutation of $C\times L$ balls, but not all permutations are valid.

**So how to calculate the number of legal states?**

---

- Detailed rules

1. Full tube is illegal in the initial state
2. Tube rotation is considered the same
3. Color rotation is considered the same

Rotation means the exchange of any $k$ colors/tubes.

For example, for three colors, including the 2-rotations $\{c_1\to c_2,c_2\to c_1\}$ and 3-rotations $\{c_1\to c_2,c_2\to c_3,c_3\to c_1\}$

[image]

Comment: Extremely **well formatted** query.  However, please work on the problem on your own and share your thoughts, by editing your query to show your work.